# An alternative method to draw the following figure

Tags: tikz-pgf

Is there an alternative method to draw the following figure?

```
\begin{picture}(130,80)(-30,10)
\thicklines
  \put(50,20){\circle*{4}}
  \put(45,10){$w$}
  \put(10,70){\circle*{4}}
  \put(5,77){$z_1$}
  \put(40,70){\circle*{4}}
  \put(35,77){$z_2$}
  \put(60,70){\circle*{1}}
  \put(65,70){\circle*{1}}
  \put(70,70){\circle*{1}}
  \put(90,70){\circle*{4}}
  \put(85,77){$z_d$}
  \put(50,20){\line(-4,5){40}}
  \put(50,20){\line(-1,5){10}}
  \put(50,20){\line(4,5){40}}
\end{picture}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

drawn as tree growing north:

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3mm]{standalone}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
                grow = north,
     sibling distance = 12mm,
       level distance = 21mm,
             N/.style = {circle, fill, minimum size=3pt,
                        inner sep=0pt, outer sep=0pt,
                        label=#1},
                        semithick
                        ]
\node[N=below:$w$] {}
    child {node[N=$z_4$] {}}
    child {node[draw=none] {\dots} edge from parent[draw=none]}
    child {node[N=$z_2$] {}}
    child {node[N=$z_1$] {}}
;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to tilt an edge clockwise or anticlockwise with x node fixed @Zarko

Comment: i'm afraid that i don't understand what you mean ...  (i) the first child in code (looking from top down) is  the last on image. (ii) direction of tree is  determined by option `grow` (north or up, left, right, down, see, chapter *Making Trees Grow* in *tikz & pgf manual v 3.0.1a, pp 316*. manual is part of your tikz installation and it also available on ctan.

Answer (score 6):

Another alternative in [Metapost](http://www.tug.org/metapost.html), here wrapped up in `luamplib`, so compile with `lualatex` (or adapt...).  Change `N` to the number of nodes you want (within reason):

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{luatex85}
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{luamplib}
\begin{document}
\mplibtextextlabel{enable}
\begin{mplibcode}
beginfig(1);
    numeric N, u, v;
    N = 5;
    u = 5cm / N;
    v = 1cm;
    for i=1 upto N:
        z[i] = (i-1/2(N+1), 2) xscaled u yscaled v;
        if i = N-1:
            label("$\cdots$", z[i]);
        else:
            draw origin -- z[i] withcolor 3/4 red;
            dotlabel.top("$z_{" & if i=N: "n" else: decimal i fi & "}$", z[i]);
        fi
    endfor
    dotlabel.bot("$w$", origin);
endfig;
\end{mplibcode}
\end{document}
```

### Notes

- You don't have to declare `numeric` variables, but it helps to make sure they start undefined.
- Plain Metapost defines `z$` (where `$` is any suitable suffix) to be a pair variable, automatically.
- The `luamplib` option `\mplibtextextlabel{enable}` option means all labels are processed by LaTeX and you can concatenate parts of strings together with `&` before they are passed out for formatting
- `decimal i` generates a string representation of the numeric variable `i`.
- Note how you can use `if ... fi` constructions "traditionally" or "inline".

Answer (score 5):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[mystyle/.style={fill,circle,inner sep=1.5pt,outer sep=0}]
    \node[mystyle,label=-90:$w$] (w) at (50pt,20pt) {};
    \node[mystyle,label=90:$z_1$] (z1) at (10pt,70pt) {};
    \node[mystyle,label=90:$z_2$] (z2) at (35pt,70pt) {};   
    \node (zd) at (65pt,70pt) {$\cdots$};
    \node[mystyle,label=90:$z_4$] (z4) at (85pt,70pt) {};   
    \draw[thick]\foreach\z in{1,2,4}{(w)--(z\z)};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{picture}(130,80)(-30,10)
\thicklines
  \put(50,20){\circle*{4}}
  \put(45,10){$w$}
  \put(10,70){\circle*{4}}
  \put(5,77){$z_1$}
  \put(40,70){\circle*{4}}
  \put(35,77){$z_2$}
  \put(60,70){\circle*{1}}
  \put(65,70){\circle*{1}}
  \put(70,70){\circle*{1}}
  \put(90,70){\circle*{4}}
  \put(85,77){$z_d$}
  \put(50,20){\line(-4,5){40}}
  \put(50,20){\line(-1,5){10}}
  \put(50,20){\line(4,5){40}}
\end{picture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikzpicture}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.1]
\tikzstyle{every node}=[circle, fill=black!,inner sep=0pt, minimum width=4pt]
\node (n_1) at (0,0)[label=below:{$x$}] {};
\node (n_2) at (-1.5,1.5)[label=above:{$y_1$}] {};
\node (n_3) at (-.7,1.8)[label=above:{$y_2$}] {};
\node (n_4) at (.1,1.85)[label=above:{$y_3$}] {};
\node (n_5) at (1.5,1.5)[label=above:{$y_m$}] {};
\foreach \from/\to in
{ n_1/n_5, n_1/n_4, n_1/n_3, n_1/n_2}\draw (\from) -- (\to);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How to add those small dots (given in the question) in this code @
Zarko